# How to create class variable that not share state between Children

Tags: ruby

I wish to create a way to make Children classes express some business definitions on Class Level.

I tried to use Class Variables for that, but i found that they share state between all Classes, so once i define the Second Class, the "@@attribute" class var changes its value for all adjacent Class instances.

```rb
class Parent
  def self.type(value)
    @@_type = value
  end

  def render
    puts @@_type
  end
end

class Children < Parent
  type "name"
end

Children.new.render # Result: name. Expected: name

class Children2 < Parent
  type "title"
end

Children2.new.render # Result: title. Expected: title
Children.new.render # Result: title. Expected: name
```

How can i create this DSLs in the most simple and direct way?
This is a common pattern for several Ruby Gems, like HTTParty, Virtus, and etc.

I even tried to look at their source code to understand how its done, but it seems too much complex for what i want.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Class variables are one of a triumvirate of Ruby tools that most experienced Rubiests rarely, if ever, use.<sup>1</sup>. Instead you want to use a *class-level instance variable*, `Parent` being an instance of the class `Class`.

```
class Parent
  def self.type=(value)
    @type = value
  end

  def self.type
    @type
  end

  def render
    puts self.class.type
  end
end
```

```
class Children < Parent
  self.type = "name"
end

Children.new.render
  #=> "name"

class Children2 < Parent
  self.type = "title"
end
```

```
Children2.new.render
  #=> "title"
Children.new.render
  #=> "name"
```

Firstly, the class method `type=` is called a "setter" and the class method "type" is called a "getter". You had a setter `type`, taking an argument. If you do that, how will you just get its value? To use it as a getter as well you'd have to do something like the following:

```
  def self.type=(value=nil)
    if value.nil?
      @type
    else
      @type = value
    end
  end
```

Here it would make more sense to just define a getter

```
  def self.type
    @type
  end
```

and having no setter, just writing, for example, `@type = "name"`.

That is kludgy and only works if you don's want to set `@type` to `nil`. You could also leave your method as a setter and use `self.class.instance_variable_get(:@type)` to get its value, but that's equally awful. It's best to have a setter and a getter.

When using the setter we need to preface `type` with `self.` to tell Ruby we wish to invoked the getter and not set a local variable `type` to a given value. Of course we could instead just write, for example, `@type = "title".

The conventional way to create a setter and a getter is to write `attr_accessor :type` (invoking the class method [Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)). As class methods are stored in a class' singleton class, that could be done as follows<sup>2</sup>:

```
class Parent
  class << self
    attr_accessor :type
  end
  def render
    puts self.class.type
  end
end
```

```
class Children < Parent
  self.type = "name"
end

Children.new.render
  #=> "name"

class Children2 < Parent
  self.type = "title"
end
```

Now consider the instance method `Parent#render`. Being an instance method its receiver is an instance of the class (or a subclass), say `parent = Parent.new`. That means that when `render` is invoked within the method `self` equals `parent`. We want to invoke the class method `type`, however. We must therefore convert `parent` to `Parent`, which we do with `self.class`.

<sup>1. The other two (in my opinion, of course) are global variables and `for` loops. Their popularity among Ruby newbies is probably due to the fact that they tend to make their debut in Chapter 1 of many learning-Ruby books.</sup>

<sup>2. There are many ways to define `attr_accessor` in `Parent`'s singleton class. Two others are `singleton_class.instance_eval do { attr_accessor :type }` and `singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :type)`</sup>.

Comment: Even though I don't like the name (_class_ instance variable is just an instance variable), it's good to be able to tell them apart. I don't think there's a better term for it...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but that is exactly what it is an instance_variable for that class because every class is an instance of the the class `Class`. What could be so confusing about that :) and @Cary `self.type` (*hint,hint*)

Comment: "That is very kludgy" - matter of taste, I guess. I find it clean and intuitive (when used where appropriate, like this case). "and only works if you don't want to set @type to nil" - ah, but you can have an arbitrary empty value. `def self.type(val = :no_one_will_ever_intentionally_use_this_symbol)`

Comment: @Sergio, no I haven't run the code in my SO answers for years. I used to do that religiously, but it always ran fine so I figured it was a waste of time. Just to satisfy you I ran my code here and it was fine. Second topic: isn't that just when someone will use  `:no_one_will_ever_intentionally_use_this_symbol`? Man, was that whooped with an ugly stick or what?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I've edited to use the expression "class-level instance variable", which I've noticed is favoured by some.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the first code does not work without `self.type="name"` with just `type="name"` the render method shows `nil` which I think was Sergio's point

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky. Oh, well. I knew I'd eventually make a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i have no idea why it worked, but it worked this way:

```rb
class Parent
  class << self
    attr_accessor :_type

    def type(value)
      self._type = value
    end
  end

  def render
    puts self.class._type
  end
end
```

I really wish to understand why, but "self.class", and "class << self" seems a lot of dark to me.

Light?

Comment: This is not really an answer but is an elaboration of your question. I suggest you edit your question to include this and delete this answer.

Comment: "I really wish to understand why" - this basically boils down to difference between class variables (`@@type`) and instance variables (`@type`). The latter, even if it's defined on a class object, has smaller area of effect.

Comment: `class << self` is modifying the eigen class (singleton) for the class `Parent` and defining methods in that scope. `Parent` now has these methods as class instance methods through inheritance.